# Como imprimir mantendo o layout da página?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema básico de controle hoteleiro. 
Ao registrar a entrada do hóspede em uma suíte, preciso imprimir um "recibo" para o cliente, porém colocando somente a função `window.print()` do JavaScript não está imprimindo como gostaria. 
A imagem abaixo mostra como está o *layout* da página e como está saindo a impressão (direita).

[image]

O conteúdo do recibo todo dentro de uma `div` contendo outras DIVs dentro, pois estou montando o sistema com Bootstrap e é necessário ir inserindo as divs para utilizar as grids do Bootstrap (tabelas responsivas). Segue estrutura básica da `div` em questão:

```
<div id="recibo" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="background-color:#d7d8da;">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">Comprovante de Entrada em Suíte</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color: initial;">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="row" style="background-color: initial;">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
            <b>Número da Suíte</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
            <?php
                echo $num_suite;
            ?>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Há alguma forma de mandar imprimir preservando todo o *layout* da página do jeito que está no lado esquerdo da imagem (HTML, CSS etc)?

Comment: Se você adicionar novamente o arquivo CSS indicando `media` como `print`, o que acontece? Algo como: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="print" />`

Comment: veja se essas dicas podem lhe ajudar  https://tableless.com.br/dicas-de-css-para-impressao/

Comment: Pelo visto não dá mesmo, estou desde ontem pesquisando tentando encontrar uma alternativa e não encontro nada que permita imprimir colorido, parece que é padrão a impressão ignorar todo o CSS da página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para imprimir do jeito que você quer, utilize `"col-xs-6"` no lugar de `"col-sm-6"`.

O Bootstrap entende a impressão como sendo o equivalente ao `"xs"`.

Comment: Fazendo isso, só mantém o layout das colunas na impressão, mas não mantém a cor de fundo, a cor do cabeçalho da tabela etc.

Comment: Não tem como imprimir cor de fundo. Isso é uma limitação do CSS. Não dá pra imprimir colocando imagem, nem setando cor de fundo.
A solução que eu usei uma vez foi incluir uma imagem normal (tag `<img>` com posicionamento absoluto e `z-index: 1` (para ficar por trás). Talvez ajude.

Comment: Pelo visto não dá mesmo, estou desde ontem pesquisando tentando encontrar uma alternativa e não encontro nada. De qualquer forma a sua dica do Bootstrap já foi bastante valiosa.